# Jquery, submited form keep changing its param

Tags: jquery, html, forms

I tried to pass some value to another page through url. I can't hardcode it inline in the html because I need to get some information from several step first. So I need to change the action in form before it submitted.

This is the form

```
<form id="addActForm" class="w3-container formInput" method="GET" action="">
    <p>
        <input class="w3-radio" type="radio" name="typeAct" value="1">
        <i class="fa fa-file-text-o"></i> <label>Assignment</label></p>
    <p>
        <input class="w3-radio" type="radio" name="typeAct" value="2" >
        <i class="fa fa-file-o"></i> <label>File</label></p>
    <input id="btnSubmit" type="button" class="w3-btn w3-black" value="Add">
</form>
```

and this is the script that handle the action

```
$('#btnSubmit').click(function(){
    var action = PATH + "code=" + code + "&topic=" + topic + "&type=" + type;
    console.log(action);
    $('#addActForm').attr('action', action);
    $('#addActForm').submit();
});
```

If I delete the submit and see the console, it already give me what i want, example

> addingActivity.php?code=AIF315&topic=1&type=2

I even check the form action manually through the console and it has the right value. But when I try to submit, it gives me this instead

> addingActivity.php?typeAct=2

Why is it changing back? What is wrong?

Thanks :)

Comment: Where are the code. topic, and type variables coming from? Don't see them defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that when you submit the form as a GET it encodes the form values (from your inputs) and puts them in the URL of the request. So your params will get replaced by whatever the form generates. This is why you get a `typeAct=2` because you have an input with `name="typeAct"` in the form

Instead, your action should just be the base path and use hidden fields to generate what you want

```
<form id="addActForm" class="w3-container formInput" method="GET" action="<YOUR_BASE_URL>">
    <p>
        <input class="w3-radio" type="radio" name="type" value="1">
        <i class="fa fa-file-text-o"></i> <label>Assignment</label></p>
    <p>
        <input class="w3-radio" type="radio" name="type" value="2" >
        <i class="fa fa-file-o"></i> <label>File</label></p>

    <input type="hidden" class="code" name="code" value="AIF315" />
    <input type="hidden" class="topic" name="topic" value="1" />

    <input id="btnSubmit" type="button" class="w3-btn w3-black" value="Add">
</form>
```

Then just set them with JS before submission and let the browser do the url encoding for you

```
$('#btnSubmit').click(function(){
    $("input.code").val(code);
    $("input.topic").val(topic);
    $('#addActForm').submit();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try something like that:

```
var element = YOUR FORM ELEMENT;

var topic= document.createElement("input"); 
    code.setAttribute("type","hidden"); 
    code.setAttribute("topic",topic);   
    element.form.appendChild(topic); 


 var code = document.createElement("input"); 
    code.setAttribute("type","hidden"); 
    code.setAttribute("code",code);   
    element.form.appendChild(code);


 var type= document.createElement("input"); 
    code.setAttribute("type","hidden"); 
    code.setAttribute("type",type);   
    element.form.appendChild(type);

 element.form.action = PATH ;   
 element.form.submit();
```